# UIScrollView animation laggy

Tags: ios, ipad, uiscrollview

I'm writing an reader for iPad that shows images (1024x1322 max) in a UIScrollView

each image is loaded in a background thread when it's needed (during scroll) (there is always 3 images loaded at max).

My problem is: when the data is loaded I'm updating the UIImageView, in my background thread like that:

```
image= [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: file];
[content setImage:image]
```

It seems to 'lock' the main thread and make the UISCrollView animation not smooth at all.

Thank you in advance for any clue

Comment: Have you resolved this? I ran into a similar issue when caching images on disk in an image-intensive app. Still don't know of a good solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756863/scroll-view-and-table-view-performance-when-loading-images-from-disk

Comment: And you should not access UIKit inside a thread other than the main thread - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKit_Framework/Introduction/Introduction.html - "UIKit classes should be used only from an application’s main thread"

Answer (score 2):

You should *never* set the image of an image view (or any property of any UI component for that matter) from a background thread. `UIKit` is *not* thread-safe. You need to pass the image to the main thread, using either GCD or `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`.

Answer (score 0):

do something like this in your background thread, instead of using UIImage

```
CGDataProviderRef dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename("file.png"); 
CGImageRef image = CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider(dataProvider, NULL, NO, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
```

pass back the image ref to your main thread then create the UIImage with [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image]

Hope this helps